# Tax and Shipping API plugins

Tags: plugins, plugin-craftcommerce

Are there any tax plugins available for some of the major sales tax API services (i.e. TaxJar, Taxamo, Avalara)?

Are there any shipping plugins available for some of the major shipping services (i.e. UPS, FedEx)?

The reason for my questions is that it would seem that the Craft Commerce plugin is extremely limited in those 2 areas.

Answer (score 1):

Craft Commerce is a young product and as such, there are indeed limited options for third party plugins.

Good news, though - writing a shipping plugin at least is not difficult (well, the Commerce part isn't - the API of the shipping service is of course, up to that shipping service!). See https://craftcommerce.com/docs/shipping-methods to get started.  I've personally written a live rates plugin (for TNT) and several unique table based ones, and I've found the process easy and clean.

There is already a ShipStation plugin - https://onedesigncompany.com/craft-cms/plugins/oneshipstation - and ShipStation handles UPS, FedEx etc.

On tax, I don't know a lot about that and so far I think Commerce's tax support is a little limited (e.g. no tax on shipping support).

Fortunately, Craft/Commerce support is excellent and if you do need to integrate a new service, you'll fine Luke Holder and the rest of the Craft team are very helpful with that sort of thing - and of course they're keen to see the Craft/Commerce eco-system grow.  support@craftcommerce.com is the address you need :)

Comment: Thanks so much! I am new to both Craft and Craft Commerce, and I am looking forward to developing some custom plugins. Your answer certainly helps give much more confidence in the whole situation. If I had enough reputation points, I would gladly upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with[Vip Parcel](https://vipparcel.com/) if you are interested in better discount rates on USPS.

Especially if you are sending small packages domestically or internationally, the service they offer is unbeatable.

You can upload batches in XML uploads, integrate your e-bay account, schedule pick-ups, create accounts and sub-accounts and fill out custom forms for international. It's great.